# Why no typelcass constraint on StateT definition

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad, type-constraints

Here is the StateT definition in the transformers lib:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a,s) }
```

Here `m` is a `Monad`

Then why in the definition there is no contraint on it? Something like:

```
newtype (Monad m) => StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a,s) }
```